# IllegalStateException: No Activity

Tags: android

I am having a very odd problem that for the life of me I cant figure out. I have an app that is about finished. I have started testing it on different versions of Android and different screen sizes/densities in the emulator. Everything worked fine until I got to Android 3.1 and 3.2 (Honeycomb). I get an `IllegalStateException: No Activity` every time the app starts. I first thought it was my app so I went through the stack trace and there was no mention of any method or class in my app. So I then tried it on all Android versions supported by my app and it worked in every version except Honeycomb. I Googled Honeycomb and `IllegalStateException: No Activity` and didn't find anything. So I then looked at the screen size and realized the only skin for Honeycomb is WXGA. I checked all my drawables, I'm using one for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi. But just in case I threw all the drawables my app needs into the default drawable folder and still had the same problem. I'm using the default folder for all my other resources so I know that isn't the cause. I then tried a smaller screen size and to my amazement it worked. So I then tested it on Android 4.1 and used 1280x800 and a density of 160 to mimic WXGA. And it worked just fine. So its specific to WXGA(1280x800 mdpi) and Honeycomb. I debugged and stepped through my code and it actually successfully makes it through `onCreate()`. I think it actually went through `onCreate()` twice. I am not overriding `onResume()` in this `Activity`. I spent more time in Google land but I just cant find anything related to what I am experiencing. Just in case it helps here is my `onCreate()`. If anybody can shed any light on this I will forever be in your debt.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    mResources = getResources();
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mUrl = mResources.getString(R.string.rate_url);
    mEmailSubject = mResources.getString(R.string.email_subject);
    mChoose = mResources.getString(R.string.email_choose);
    mSendTo = mResources.getString(R.string.email_send_to);
    mLoadingPlaces = mResources.getString(R.string.places_loading);
    mAmazonAppStore = mResources.getString(R.string.amazon_app);

    mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tip_btn);
    mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preference);
    mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate_btn);
    mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feedback_btn);

    // Load the font and the set the font for each Button.
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/ArchitectsDaughter.ttf");

    mButton1.setTypeface(tf);
    mButton2.setTypeface(tf);
    mButton3.setTypeface(tf);
    mButton4.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well just out of curiosity I went back and tried it again. I was gonna install it and open it multiple times to see if it worked any of the times. And to my amazement it worked EVERY time!!!!! I have been playing with it for a few minutes uninstalling and reinstalling it and its working. It was weird because I know I have tested it on Honeycomb before and it worked in the past. So I dont know if it was maybe just a glitch in the emulator but it seems ok now. I just wish I had a device with this configuration to test it on. So if anyone has any ideas or suggestions on what MIGHT have been causing this I am willing to look into each and every one to be sure.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784850/application-crashes-on-rotation-without-stacktrace#comment17335365_12784850. PLain weird i try to replicate this error but I dont ind any way