# Application crashes on rotation without stackTrace

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-support-library

I'm having a very strange problem with my app, which consists of an Activity and 2 Fragments (android.support.v4.app.Fragment).

The problem is when I rotate my tablet : the app crashes right away.

A few days before, everything was working fine, but I had to change packages name, that threw a few errors but I manage to correct them.
Problem appeared right after that, but I just can't find where is the error.
Here is the Logcat I get right after the app is destroyed, restarted, resumed and created :

```
10-08 17:00:14.930: D/dalvikvm(18155): GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 8% free 7792K/8455K,  paused 1ms+4ms
10-08 17:00:14.930: D/AndroidRuntime(18155): Shutting down VM
10-08 17:00:14.930: W/dalvikvm(18155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bee1f8)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1854)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:431)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleMessage(FragmentActivity.java:90)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
10-08 17:00:14.938: E/AndroidRuntime(18155):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The problem comes from FragmentManager but why, I don't know, as I don't have any details.
I tried a solution i found on this site to get more info, by catching uncaught exception, but the result i got was the same Logcat repeated again and again until some kind of out of memory error happened(too many strings in the logcat).

My Activity's layout is the following one, it works well with android lifecycle, but not with screen rotation :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id = "@+id/mainview"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/missionFragment"
        android:layout_width="350dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MissionFragment">       
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MapFragment">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest is right there :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MySIGActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If anyone has any idea on where would the error come, on which android lifecycle method, that would be welcomed!

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1.1:**
Here is onCreate method of my main Activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    currentEtape = 1;

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    // Désactiver l'affichage du titre de l'application et son icône
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
    trackingGPS = prefs.getBoolean("trackingGPS", false);
    if(trackingGPS){
        TextView viewTrackingActive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_notif_tracking);
        viewTrackingActive.setText(this.getString(R.string.active));
        viewTrackingActive.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
    }
    else{
        TextView viewTrackingDesactive = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_notif_tracking);
        viewTrackingDesactive.setText(this.getString(R.string.desactive));
        viewTrackingDesactive.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
    }

    // No interaction with Fragment or Activity classes in these methods
    instanciateLayersDialog();
    instanciateBasemapDialog();

}
```

And onResume method :

```
public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
            trackingGPS = prefs.getBoolean("trackingGPS", false);
            System.out.println("activity resume");
}
```

Comment: You're not putting any info of your FragmentActivity, that should help. Specifically OnCreate and onResume.
Anyways, I've had very frustrating similar problems: one was with memory leak; in the emulator I was getting leap error message on screen rotation but not on a htc desire, for instance. Second, some methods of  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager collide with android.FragmentManager and thus when copying pasting in a project without v4 support, there are this kind of error. Have you checked which you are using? Try ysing fully qualified names and put some code

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am using FramentManager from v4 support, I double checked and there is no reference to basic FragmentManager... I hoped the problme could come from there but it's not. I'll update my post to add onCreate and OnResume.

Comment: I think the first you posted is onCreate, right? Both say onResume.  In that case have you tried in different devices  Or at least in different AVDs? I'm just guessing, this "No Activity" thrown as an IllegalStateException ..

Comment: You were right. I just put the correct method, thanks.

Comment: BTW, I found this question that is related to my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380920/illegalstateexception-no-activity. I tried changing sdk versions but it doesn't help.

Comment: My guess is this: it's an issue with an emulator you are using. Create new AVD's (new emulator instances) and/or try on other physical phones.  If this doesn't work then we should look at the activities you have. You have a main activity and..?

Comment: btw, Sysyem.out.println ? you mean Log.d(event,sting) ? ;)

Comment: Actually I'm not using an emulator but a tablet device ;-) and yes the sysout should be Log.d(...) But nevermind, I found the solution! I replaced the support.v4 import by android.app for Fragments. And now I have no issue! So the problem was somehow related to Fragment from support.v4 package. I still don't know where however. But thanks for your help quinestor ;-)

Comment: Ya but removing the support package is not a solution! I'm seeing the same issue, on an actual device (Xoom) when I am doing a Replace transaction on a Fragment that has already been added once before, and is not being re-added. (Swapping out fragments in a FrameLayout)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this answers the problem of the original poster, but I had this same problem when I had an onPause() method in my main Activity that looked like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onResume();

    ...do other stuff...
}
```

As you can see, it was just a typo, but it took me a while to track it down since the error message "No Activity" was so vague. ("super.onResume" should have been "super.onPause", if it's not obvious.)

If this is not your exact issue, I believe it had something to do with the original Fragment not getting destroyed (by the proper onPause() call in my case).

Comment: This should be the right answer. It helped with something I had been worrying over for hours.

Comment: this also happens when activity and fragments are rebuilding after switching back from airplane mode. Good catch Reynard.

Comment: Funny, I had exactly the same problem! :)

Answer (score -6):

I found the problem: the **android.support.v4.app package** was the issue. I replaced all the imports with standard Fragment imports from android.app package.

Using this package my compatibility towards Android 2.0 branch is now broken, but in my case it's not a problem.

Comment: Accepting your own answer when the answer = support library broken, is pretty lame, at least leave the question open until a real answer comes in.