# Getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity when resuming an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm getting a weird error in one of my activities. I can't figure out why this is happening.

I have an `Activity` which displays search results to the user. When he taps on one of them, a detailed page for that result is shown, and when he closes that `Activity` it goes back to the search result screen. It works fine for the most part, except on certain devices where it crashes as soon as the `Activity` resumes.

The stack trace is also useless as it is being thrown internally by the support fragment manager.

```
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1871)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:455)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleMessage(FragmentActivity.java:91)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-18 15:32:48.987: E/AndroidRuntime(26456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 15:32:48.987: W/ActivityManager(241):   Force finishing activity com.my.app/.SearchActivity
```

My `Activity` is extending `FragmentActivity`, but only because I need to use the `LoaderManager`. Moving to the standard library is out of the question since my app has to support Android 2.3.

I have tried updating to the newer version of the support library, and reverting to an older version, but no luck.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace ?

Comment: That is the complete stack trace. It's all being thrown internally. Since it's happening only on some devices, I suspect it's an issue with the device customizations, but I have no idea how to go about solving it.

Comment: do you have imported android.support.v4.jar?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't be able to run the app at all.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I got the answer - It's the same as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784850/application-crashes-on-rotation-without-stacktrace?rq=1) one.

Someone had overriden `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` in the details page but was calling `super.onResume()` instead. I do wish that the error message had been more clear though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is due to activity automaticay restared so just set lounch mode single task